# Find out all testcases not assigned to a test plan in Kiwi TCMS

Tags: kiwi-tcms

Is there a way to find out all testcases not assigned to a test plan?

We have many test cases and it is difficult to find out which test cases have not yet been assigned to a test plan.

Comment: can you describe your use case ? Why is it important that you are able to find all test cases which aren't assigned to a TP?  As a side note: you can add test cases to arbitrary test runs as well, even if such TCs aren't assigned to any TP.  How does that play into your use case ?

Comment: Currently we have many testcase and these testcases are assigned to a specific testplan. Each testplan represents a different component. If something has changed in a component, we can create and execute a testrun from the specific testplan. On the other hand, if someone creates a new testcase that is not assigned to any testplan, the testcase will never be executed. So first I have to find out which testcase is not assigned to the specific testplan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finding test cases which are not attached to a Test Plan is possible, but not very handy ATM.  Please open an issue on GitHub to request an enhancement for the Test Case search page.

If you use the JavaScript API inside a browser's console then the following will work for you:

`jsonRPC('TestCase.filter', {plan:4638}, console.log)` - will filter all test cases attached to TP 4638.

`jsonRPC('TestCase.filter', {plan:null}, console.log)` - will filter all test cases which are not attached to any plans. On https://public.tenant.kiwitcms.org currently this returns 117 cases.

*Disclaimer: this answer has been provided to you by a Kiwi TCMS team member.*

Comment: Can you please describe how can I execute your commands with Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Hi Alexander. By long-standing convention, editors will remove here (a) requests for upvotes on Stack Overflow, (b) requests for upvotes/stars on other platforms like GitHub, (c) requests for financial donations. However I think these things are OK: (a) requests for upvotes on feature platforms (it does not directly benefit the person who asks), (b) a note to indicate that a poster is part of a team or has a specific employer (it helps readers become aware of a conflict of interests).

Comment: I think there are resources on _Meta Stack Overflow_ about this - I can help you find some if you are interested. Or, if you find you would like more resources (e.g. specifically about requesting financial donations) then you could ask a question about that (and I'd be happy to write an answer).

Comment: @halfer thanks for the notice. If you have a link handy please post it here and I will read the rules of the convention more carefully. Our team would like to continue being a good open source citizen.

Comment: No worries. I have done a few searches on Meta, and finally found [a discussion about asking for votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350915/can-i-request-for-vote-up).

Comment: Here is [a question about asking for donations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403856/should-users-be-allowed-to-request-donations-in-the-comments-under-their-answers). Although it specifically asks about requests in comments, the answer from a mod covers several ways in which the request could be made. One could argue that the mod was addressing requests for donations for Stack Overflow assistance, rather than for an open source project; I doubt they would be treated differently, but you can always ask a new Meta question if you wish.